# How to get each 10 days of data between year in sql/postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm trying to write a query where i want to get every 10 days of data between 2 years.
i'm getting data between particular date to current date. but i don't know how to get each 10 days of data
in between the selected date.

Here's my current query. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

```sql
SELECT "Name","id",cast(sum("amount")/100 as money) AS "AMOUNT", sum(1) AS "COUNT" from table1
WHERE "DATETIME" BETWEEN '01-01-2019' AND now() - interval '10 days'
GROUP BY "Name","id"
HAVING sum("amount") > 3000
```

**Expecting it to get data of each 10 days from 01-01-2019 to current date**

Comment: Put some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you have a load of data that is day by day and you want to group it up into blocks of 10 days starting from 2019-01-01, then you can generate a time series of every 10 days and join the real data to it:

```
select 
  tendays.day, 
  "Name", 
  "id", 
  cast(sum("amount")/100 as money) as "AMOUNT", 
  sum(1) as "COUNT"   
from 
  generate_series ('2019-01-01'::timestamp, now()::timestamp, '10 day'::interval) AS tendays(day) 
  LEFT JOIN
  (select '2019-01-02'::timestamp as "DATETIME", 'a' as "Name", 'b' as "id", 1 as "amount" ) t1
  ON 
    t1."DATETIME" >= tendays.day AND 
    t1."DATETIME" < (tendays.day + interval '10 days')
group by "Name","id", tendays.day
having sum("amount") > 3000
```

I wasn't really clear on whether you wanted to keep the existing grouping of Name and ID or not. Also, be careful with your HAVING - you'll only get results if a name/id pair has total amount over 3000 in a ten day block

I've made it a left join so you can remove the HAVING and see if any ten day blocks have no data meeting the criteria. It can be swapped for INNER JOIN if this is not important to you

Answer (score 0):

Essentially to get items, separated by a specific interval of time, you can `GROUP BY` them by using a specific date difference:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 10, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2019-01-01'), 0)
...
```

Please try experimenting with the above to match your exact needs.

**Update:**

For Postgres the `DATEDIFF` alternative could be using the `EXTRACT` or `DATEPART`.
Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name, for noticing that.

Comment: There is no datediff in Postgres

Comment: can you be more specific ? what u mention by DAY. am getting error at DAY

Comment: In T-SQL `DAY` is a built-in keyword, but in Postgres it seems the alternative could be 'day'.

Comment: I don't really understand what that datediff does, but it seems it's complicated way of adding 10 days to a date? That would be `date '2019-01-01' + 10` in Postgres